Disable Pressable while Swipeable is swiping
I have a <Swipeable/> component, and a <Pressable/> component inside of it. The problem I have is that during swipes, the onPress for the pressable component will trigger.
I checked Swipeables properties to see if theres something I can use to check if its currently swiping, and then just update a state to disable pressable.
However, none of the properties: onSwipeableWillOpen or renderRightActions provide instant feedback when swiping starts.

I got the same problem (on iOS). I searched everything, but could not found a proper solution. However, the following fix does it for me:
I got a set of messages, whenever I swipe on messgae I add it to an array of IDs (also used for some styling). if on onPress the ID is in the array, just don't trigger the function.
messages.map((message) => {
  const swiped = swipedMessages.includes(message.id);
  return (
    <Swipeable
      key={message.id}
      onSwipeableOpenStartDrag={() => setSwipedMessages( swipedMessages.concat([message.id]) )}
      onSwipeableClose={() => setSwipedMessages( swipedMessages.filter( (m) => m !== message.id ) )}
    >
      <Pressable
        onPress={() => {
          if(!swiped) {
            router.push(...);
          }
        }}
      >
        ... 
      </Pressable>
    </Swipeable>
  );
})

Hope it helps, if you haven't figured out some better solution. (if yes, please let me know) :)
